# Rails admin panel: User list showing bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, web-frontend

I'm currently trying to get used to rails by creating a website with admin and user. However, when displaying the user list in admin dashboard, for some reasons these lines appear:

> [#<User id: 1, email: "admin@gmail.com", password_digest: [FILTERED],
> created_at: "2022-08-09 03:47:52.264555000 +0000", updated_at:
> "2022-08-09 03:47:52.264555000 +0000", firstname: nil, lastname: nil,
> last_change: nil>, #<User id: 3, email: "asd@asd.com",
> password_digest: [FILTERED], created_at: "2022-08-19
> 08:32:37.086901000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-08-19 08:32:37.086901000
> +0000", firstname: nil, lastname: nil, last_change: nil>, #<User id: 4, email: "asd@gmail.com", password_digest: [FILTERED], created_at:
> "2022-08-19 08:32:58.497826000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-08-19
> 08:32:58.497826000 +0000", firstname: nil, lastname: nil, last_change:
> nil>]

This is the code that I used to display user list:

```
<%= @users.each do |hello| %>
 <%= form_with model: @user, url: '/admin/users/delete' do |f| %>
    <%= hello.email %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag( :id, hello.id) %>
    <%=f.submit "Delete"%>
  <%end%>
  <hr>
<%end%>
```

And this is the picture of the display I got:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ERF.png)

Really appreciate if you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `<%= %>` syntax (notice the `=`) executes ruby code and prints the result to your html.

This means that `<%= @users.each do |hello| %>` will, beside looping, also print the result of `@users` to your html file, which is the weird text you are seeing.

To solve this, simply change

`<%= @users.each do |hello| %>`

to

`<% @users.each do |hello| %>`

(so without `=` sign). This will still execute the ruby code, but not pass its return value to your html.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
<%= @users.each do |hello| %>
```

by

```
<% @users.each do |hello| %>
```

Comment: Thankss for helping!